# Using createOrUpdate for multiple child records in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, relationship

I have a "shipment" model which has many "shipment_details" model records.

```
public function shipment_details(){
      return $this->hasMany('App\Shipment_Detail', 'shipmentID','id');
}
```

I don't have a problem initially creating "shipment_details" when I create a "shipment" record.

My problem arises when I want to update the "shipment" record and I end up needing to add an additional "shipment_detail" record underneath.

At the moment my html of the "shipment_details" is as such from the blade:

```
<tbody>
    @foreach($shipment_details as $sd)
    <tr style="height:40px">
        <td style="width:8%;text-align:center;">{{Form::text('shipment_details['.$sd->id.'][piecesNumber]', $sd->pieces_number, array('class' => 'form-control','placeholder'=>'No. Pieces','required','id'=>'piecesNumber'))}}
        </td>
        <td style="width:16%;text-align:center;">
            {!! Form::select('shipment_details['.$sd->id.'][piecesType]', $piecetypes, $sd->pieces_type, ['id' => 'pieces_type', 'class' => 'form-control full-width','required']) !!}    
        </td>
        <td>
            {!! Form::select('shipment_details['.$sd->id.'][rateType]', $ratetypes, $sd->rate_type, ['id' => 'rateType', 'class' => 'form-control full-width','required']) !!}
        </td>
        <td style="width:16.5%;text-align:center;">
            {{Form::text('shipment_details['.$sd->id.'][weight]', $sd->weight, array('class' => 'form-control','placeholder'=>'Weight','required','id'=>'weight'))}}    
        </td>
        <td style="width:16.5%;text-align:center;">
            {{Form::select('shipment_details['.$sd->id.'][hazmat]',array(
                                    '0'=>'No',
                                    '1'=>'Yes',
                                ), $sd->hazmat, array('class' => 'form-control','id'=>'hazmat'))}}   
        </td>
        <td style="width:16.5%;text-align:center;">
                            {{Form::text('shipment_details['.$sd->id.'][description]', $sd->description, array('class' => 'form-control','placeholder'=>'Description','required','id'=>'description'))}} 
        </td>
        <td style="width:16.5%;text-align:center;">
            {{Form::text('shipment_details['.$sd->id.'][charge]', $sd->charge, array('class' => 'form-control','placeholder'=>'Charge','required','id'=>'charge'))}} 
        </td>
        <td><button type="button" name="add" id="add" class="btn btn-success">Add More</button></td>
    </tr>

    @endforeach
</tbody>
```

The add more button refers to this script:

```
<script>
 $(document).ready(function(){  
      var i=1;  
      $('#add').click(function(){  
            i++;  
           $('#freight_bill_items').append('<tr id="row'+i+'"> <td style="width:8%;text-align:center;">{{Form::text('shipment_details[piecesNumber][]', null, array('class' => 'form-control','placeholder'=>'No. Pieces','required','id'=>'piecesNumber'))}}</td><td style="width:16%;text-align:center;">{!! Form::select('shipment_details[piecesType][]', $piecetypes, 'null', ['id' => 'pieces_type', 'class' => 'form-control full-width','required']) !!} </td><td>{!! Form::select('shipment_details[rateType][]', $ratetypes, null, ['id' => 'rateType', 'class' => 'form-control full-width','required']) !!}</td><td style="width:16.5%;text-align:center;">{{Form::text('shipment_details[weight][]', null, array('class' => 'form-control','placeholder'=>'Weight','required','id'=>'weight'))}}</td><td style="width:16.5%;text-align:center;">{{Form::select('shipment_details[hazmat][]',array('No'=>'No','Yes'=>'Yes',), null, array('class' => 'form-control','id'=>'hazmat'))}}</td><td style="width:16.5%;text-align:center;">{{Form::text('shipment_details[description][]', null, array('class' => 'form-control','placeholder'=>'Description','required','id'=>'description'))}}</td><td style="width:16.5%;text-align:center;">{{Form::text('shipment_details[charge][]', null, array('class' => 'form-control','placeholder'=>'Charge','required','id'=>'charge'))}}</td><td><button type="button" name="remove" id="'+i+'" class="btn btn-danger btn_remove">X</button></td></tr>');   
      });  
      $(document).on('click', '.btn_remove', function(){  
           var button_id = $(this).attr("id");   
           $('#row'+button_id+'').remove();
           $( 'input[name^="shipment_details[charge][]"]' ).trigger( "change" );
      });

 });
</script>
```

And then at the current moment, my "shipment_details" are "saved" through the controller in the following way:

```
    foreach ( $request->shipment_details as $id => $details ) {
        $shipdetail = Shipment_Detail::find($id);
        $shipdetail->pieces_type = $details['piecesType'];
        $shipdetail->pieces_number = $details['piecesNumber'];
        $shipdetail->rate_type = $details['rateType'];
        $shipdetail->weight = $details['weight'];
        $shipdetail->charge = $details['charge'];
        $shipdetail->description = $details['description'];
        $shipdetail->hazmat = $details['hazmat'];
        // Other info to update here
        $shipdetail->save();
    }
```

So my question is, is there a way to additional "shipment_details"? Would it require using something like updateOrCreate or would it require something else?

### Update

This is how my array is posting at the moment and is currently posting with the error - Undefined index: piecesType. At the moment, if I update a current shipment_detail, it works fine, it's adding the new one that creates the problem.

```
shipment_details    

array:8 [▼
  13149 => array:7 [▼
    "piecesNumber" => "1"
    "piecesType" => "1"
    "rateType" => "1"
    "weight" => "12"
    "hazmat" => "0"
    "description" => "124"
    "charge" => "12.00"
  ]
  "piecesNumber" => array:1 [▼
    0 => "3"
  ]
  "piecesType" => array:1 [▼
    0 => "2"
  ]
  "rateType" => array:1 [▼
    0 => "2"
  ]
  "weight" => array:1 [▼
    0 => "1200"
  ]
  "hazmat" => array:1 [▼
    0 => "Yes"
  ]
  "description" => array:1 [▼
    0 => "desc2"
  ]
  "charge" => array:1 [▼
    0 => "40.00"
  ]
]
```

### Update

Shipment controller for ALEXEY

```
foreach ($request->shipment_details as $id => $details) {
            $shipdetail = Shipment_Detail::updateOrCreate(['id' => $id], [
            'pieces_type' => $details['piecesType'][0],
            'pieces_number' => $details['piecesNumber'][0],
            'rate_type' => $details['rateType'][0],
            'weight' => $details['weight'][0],
            'charge' => $details['charge'][0],
            'description' => $details['description'][0],
            'hazmat' => $details['hazmat'][0]
                ]);
        }
```

### Update

Updated with dd($id, $details);

```
13149

array:7 [▼
  "piecesNumber" => "1"
  "piecesType" => "1"
  "rateType" => "1"
  "weight" => "12"
  "hazmat" => "0"
  "description" => "124"
  "charge" => "12.00"
]
```

But it doesn't include the recently added row that I'm trying to add with this save.

Comment: What do you mean by "is there a way to additional shipment_details"?

Comment: Say when I originally created my shipment record, I added 1 shipment_detail with it, but if I go back to the shipment and want to add another while editing the shipment, I click the add button and add the additional information for another “shipment_details” record. When I click save on the shipment, it goes through, sees that there’s an existing record for the first shipment_details, updates it if necessary, and moves on to the second shipment_detail where it recognizes there is no current record and adds it.

Comment: It’s like if you were dealing with an invoice model, and you wanted to go back and add more invoice items to a particular model.

Comment: Well, then yes, you can use `updateOrCreate` method which will update existing models and create new ones if necessary.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `updateOrCreate()` like this:

```
foreach ($request->shipment_details as $id => $details) {
    $shipdetail = Shipment_Detail::updateOrCreate(['id' => $id], [
        'pieces_type' => $details['piecesType'],
        'pieces_number' => $details['piecesNumber'],
        'rate_type' => $details['rateType'],
        'weight' => $details['weight'],
        'charge' => $details['charge'],
        'description' => $details['description'],
        'hazmat' => $details['hazmat']
    ]);
}
```

Comment: I have an error that popped up called "undefined index", I believe it is how my array is posting, so I'll post it above.

Comment: @Matthew it's not related to the question, this means that in the array some data is missing. You can check it with `dd($details)`

Comment: So should l post a new question? Because all this looks like is that the new row is not posting in a single array row.

Comment: @Matthew oh I can see you've updated the question. The problem is because you have nested array, so do this `$details['description'][0]` instead of `$details['description']` if you want to get `desc2`. If you want to get the data from the first sub array, do this `$details = array_first($details);` and then work with the data as you do.

Comment: I've made an edit and included it at the bottom of the question directed at you, is that what you meant?

Comment: @Matthew I guess `dd($details)` is different from what you've shown. Please show results of `dd($details)`

Comment: I have the above code in my controller and I added dd($details) right after the end bracket of the foreach but it still comes up with Undefined index: piecesType. But the post data from the error page still says I'm sending the record fields out in separate arrays, except for the existing shipment_detail I am using as a test, which is arrayed together (see above before my specific reference to you in my question).

Comment: @Matthew put `dd` before the code. It will show contents of the variable.

Comment: Do I put that within the brackets of the foreach or before the foreach altogether?

Comment: Alright I updated my question with the results. But as I mention below the updates, the test add row isn't showing up in the dd

Comment: @Matthew the problem is the first array in the `shipment_details` is fine. It should be updated. But next 7 arrays are not fine. Looks like these 7 arrays are part of the second object array. So, you need to fix the input data.

Comment: Do you have any suggestions with what I have posted above? At the moment my current new "shipment_detail" row form is posted above. And yeah, at the moment, any existing records are updated fine, it's the creation of additional records that is the holdover.

Comment: @Matthew I can't see an error. I guess it's a good idea to post a new question not related to `updatreOrCreate()` since the code is working. Post the form, JS part and all that related to the form and the broken array.

Comment: Alright will do, thank you for your help. I'll go ahead and accept your answer. Thanks again!